# Action Float Menu Android

Tags: android, button, material-design, floating-action-button

How make action float menu with `android.support.design` 
I maked layout with these buttons, and then include to fragment layout. But maybe i make something wrong... And you have some ideas to help me. 
fab.xml

```
      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />
      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/fab_done"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_done" />
      <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/fab_cancel"
          android:layout_margin="16dp"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel" />
```

And how make animation, when I click at the button to show another buttons?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of cool libraries that were designed to make it easy to create different FABs.

[library](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) by futuresimple

[library](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton) by Clans

and [library](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button) by makovkastar

Comment: use Design Support Library http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html